# Use mask to filter data frame with value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'am trying to filter my existing dataframe and create a new dataframe containing all rows where the 'name' column values counts is greater than 20.

Here is my code:

```
mask = df['name'].value_counts() > 20

NewDf = df[mask]
```

Here is my error:

```
Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby('name', sort=False)['name'].transform('size').gt(20)]` or with map: `df[df['name'].map(df['name'].value_counts().gt(20))]`

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code

```
mask = df['name'].value_counts()
NewDf = df[df['name'].isin(mask.index[mask>20])]
```